# Error while posting relational data with Tastypie

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have these two models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    shop = ForeignKey(Shop)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_order'

class Transaction(models.Model):
    order = ForeignKey('Order')
    quantity = IntegerField()
    item = ForeignKey(Item)
    date_modified = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_transaction'
```

and two resources:

```
class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    shop = fields.ToOneField(ShopResource, 'shop')
    transactions = fields.ToManyField('TransactionResource','transaction_set', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'order'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
class TransactionResource(ModelResource):
        order = fields.ToOneField('OrderResource', 'order')
        item = fields.ToOneField('ItemResource', 'item')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Transaction.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'transaction'
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
```

I am posting this data to

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/order/
```

:

```
{
 "shop": "/api/shop/1/",
 "transactions": [
        {
                "item": "/api/item/6/",
                "quantity" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
"error_message": "Transaction has no order.",
```

if I remove

```
order = fields.ToOneField('OrderResource', 'order')
```

line from TransactionResource I am getting:

```
"error_message": "(1048, "Column 'order_id' cannot be null")",
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the related_name attribute in the transactions ToManyField definition.
instead of:

```
transactions = fields.ToManyField('ttests.api.TransactionResource','transaction_set', full=True)
```

you should use:

```
transactions = fields.ToManyField('ttests.api.TransactionResource','transaction_set', full=True, related_name='order')
```

Then tastypie will not expect that you provide the order inside the transaction when you're posting a transaction.

Comment: Now I got     "error_message": "(1048, "Column 'order_id' cannot be null")" again

Comment: I add     order = fields.ToOneField('OrderResource', 'order') and now its ok.